# Set a Drop Shadow to Border in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, border, dropshadow

I am using WPF. I have made two borders inside of the grid that comes by default when you insert a new control. One border smaller than the other one, put one next to another.

I want to apply a drop shadow in the biggest border but it simply doesn't appear when I test my application. Found many posts trying to achieve this but with a single border, I think it doesn't matter if I am using two, since I am applying the effect to just one of them.!

[image: my app design]

This is how my code looks:
[image: sidepanel]
[image: mainpanel]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. Can you provide some code? Your picture is not as clear as you think.

Comment: I updated the image. I want to apply the drop shadow to the white part of my window.

Comment: So you want the MainWindoworder to have a shadow right? An effect can be drawn only within its container. So if you wanna draw a shadow all around your border, you can put a margin all around it. NB: it seems that you overused your designer (drag, drop, manual resize, etc.). You should take a look on how to use WPF containers. Your code will be cleaner, and your app more stable and responsive.

Comment: I am new using WPF,  I have just passed from C# Winforms to WPF. Could you please point me in the right way with some guides about how I can manage my design in a better way?

Comment: Of course. I often recommend [this one](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/). You can easily refer to it when you forget how to use some control. If you go until "Databinding", you will have a clear overview about WPF.

Comment: Thank You! Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: We'd rather not since my comment is not really answering your question, and just giving suggestions. But If you manage to do what you want, you can answer your own post ^^. That would be more useful for others.

Comment: Well, I think your comment helped me a lot, that guide surely would take me in the right direction. But if that is what you want, I will answer it myself when I resolve the problem. :)  Thank You